# Installing fltk on virtualbox

Tags: linux

I tried installing fltk (and pyFltk) on a Linux virtualbox but it never works. Can someone give a very specific step-by-step instruction on how to install it.

Comment: This will be easier to answer if you describe what you've tried and what problems you experienced.  Assuming you are following some instructions, it isn't working as intended.  Some detail on what's happening will help people figure out where the problem might lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu and Debian-based operating systems open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-fltk
```

pyFltk provides a Python wrapper for the Fast Light Tool Kit cross-platform graphical user-interface library